# How to creat a new phone gap project in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, cordova

I am creating a new project in xcode 4 and after giving project name only i run the project it gives error.How to add java script files and other things and how to creat www folder i am using latest version of phongap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build and run the Xcode project for the first time you will get an error but the www will be generated. Add the www folder to your project as described here - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS